# Laravel 5 validation in model

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5

I have model like this

```
class test extends Model
{

public   $rules = [
    'title' => 'required',
    'name' => 'required',
];
protected $fillable = ['title','name'];
}
```

And controller like this

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $test=new test; /// create model object
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
             $test->rules
        ]);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return view('test')->withErrors($validator)
        }
        test::create($request->all());
 }
```

Validation show error like this

> The 0 field is required.

I want show this

> The name field is required.
>   The title field is required.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solve it

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $test=new test; /// create model object
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),$test->rules);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return view('test')->withErrors($validator)
    }
    test::create($request->all());
}
```

Comment: What if I want to make this generic (like API) so that it can be called from any view . How would I pass it to the same view (without knowing).

Comment: @VeerShrivastav maybe you can write yourself a helper class?

Answer (score 4):

You are doing it the wrong way. The `rules` array should either be in your controller or better in a [Form Request](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#form-request-validation).

Let me show you a better approach:

**Create a new Form Request** file with `php artisan make:request TestRequest`.

Example `TestRequest` class:

```php
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class TestRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation messages.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'title.required'    => 'A title is required.',
            'name.required'    => 'The name field is required'
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title' => 'required',
            'name' => 'required',
        ];
    }
}
```

**Inject the request** object into your controller method.

```php
public function store(TestRequest $request)
{
    // You don't need any validation, this is already done
    test::create($request->all());
}
```

Comment: why is it bad to store the rules with the model? why create an extra object with the request with validation login in there?

Comment: I'm from a Ruby on Rails background and have used Laravel for a couple of years, personally, I prefer the approach to validate in the model level for two main reasons: 1. Models can be changed from many places other than user inputs, to maintain the integrity of data isn't for only frontend user but everybody, including the all the developers in the project. 2. Custom Request and Validators are only for attributes that you got from controllers, they don't validate all attributes of the model, say, what if a valid purchase of 2 items makes the inventory become -1.

Comment: I would also love to know why Laravel does it this way. While I think that this answer is good in general I marked down for saying that way is "better" - "better" is subjective

Comment: Here the user wanted to put the rules into model and not into controller or form request. Because, mostly, we write rules into models, as the frameworks suggested.

Comment: According to Jeffrey Way, this is the 'preferred' method as it also allows authorisation checking. However there's no reason why the above rules method can't retrieve its rules from a static property of the model. So instead of `public $rules` it would become `public static $rules` and the above method would just return `MyModel::$rules`

Comment: I know this is old, but still applicable today. Gotta say, this answer is fundamentally wrong. The approach of storing rules on a model is not "worse", let alone "the wrong way". OOP is all about re-use, and if you're redefining rules all over the place, there's a foundational problem with your code. With a tiny bit of code, you can ensure that your rules are followed throughout the entire application, no matter the entry point (including tinker). Providing a single source of truth is _always_ favorable over loads of redefinition throughout an application.

Comment: Also coming from, ruby on rails, either I am missing something or the way laravel validation works is IMHOP not very nice

Answer (score 4):

You could also look at validating in your model and throwing a ValidationException which will be handled as usual in your controller (with the error bag etc). E.g:

```
abstract class BaseModel extends Model implements ModelInterface {
    protected $validationRules = [];

    /**
     * Validate model against rules
     * @param array $rules optional array of validation rules. If not passed will validate against object's current values
     * @throws ValidationException if validation fails. Used for displaying errors in view
     */
    public function validate($rules=[]) {
        if (empty($rules))
            $rules = $this->toArray();

        $validator = \Validator::make($rules,$this->validationRules);
        if ($validator->fails())
            throw new ValidationException($validator);
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to validate input, if successful fill this object
     * @param array $inputArray associative array of values for this object to validate against and fill this object
     * @throws ValidationException if validation fails. Used for displaying errors in view
     */
    public function validateAndFill($inputArray) {
        // must validate input before injecting into model
        $this->validate($inputArray);
        $this->fill($inputArray);
    }
}
```

Then in my Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $person = $this->personService->create($request->input());

    return redirect()->route('people.index', $person)->with('status', $person->first_name.' has been saved');
}
```

Finally in my base service class

```
abstract class BaseResourceService {
    protected $dataService;
    protected $modelClassName;

    /**
     * Create a resource
     * @param array $inputArray of key value pairs of this object to create
     * @returns $object
     */
    public function create($inputArray) {
        try {
            $arr = $inputArray;
            $object = new $this->modelClassName();
            $object->validateAndFill($arr);
            $this->dataService->create($object);
            return $object;
        }
        catch (Exception $exception) {
            $this->handleError($exception);
        }
    }
```

If the model validates it continues as usual. If there's a validation error it goes back to the previous page with the validation errors in the flash data/error bag.

I will most probably move the $person->validate() method to my service class, however it will still work as outlined above.

Comment: Nice implementation :-)
You can also have a look at [watson/validating](https://github.com/dwightwatson/validating)

Answer (score 3):

You can simply make your validation by writing in Model.

In your Model File

i.e. Models\Test.php

```
public static $createRules = [
   'name'=>'required|max:111',
   'email'=>'required|email|unique:users',
];
```

In Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
     $request->validate(ModalName::$createRules);
     $data = new ModelName();
}
```

Just do this. Everything will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The example below allows you to check the incoming data in the Model. This is necessary if the Model methods are called from different Controllers. This allows you to write validation rules for input strings once and assign them to the model.

In the example below, I created the duplicate() method, which passes the class name from App\Http\Request\EditRequest.php and $request from controller. This method copies the incoming Request from the controller and allows you to override it according to any Request::class.

store(Request $request) is a static method that can be called from the controller, passing the $request parameter. PS The controller can have its own request rules as described in the documentation.

```
use App\Http\Requests\EditRequest; // your handler
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException; 

class test extends Model
{
    private function dublicate(string $class, \Illuminate\Http\Request $request, $Model)
    {
        $Request = (new $class)->createFrom($request);
        $Request->setContainer($request->container);
        $Request->setRedirector($request->redirector);
        $validator = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::make($Request->validationData(), $Request->rules());
        $Request->getValidatorInstance();

        try {
            $validator->validate();
        } catch (ValidationException $e) {
            //$Request->validateResolved(); // call failed Validation(), will work as in the controller
            throw new \Exception($validator->errors()); // or just throw an exception
        }

        return $Request;
    }
    
    static public function store(Request $request)
    {
            $Request = dublicate(EditRequest::class, $request);     
            $validated = $Request->validated();
    }
}
```

App\Http\Request\EditRequest.php

```
class EditRequest extends Request
{
    public function rules()
    {
        $rules = [
            'title' => 'required',
            'name' => 'required',
        ];
        
        return $rules;
    }
}
```

PS duplicate() can be moved to a separate library

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).